# Assignment to static variable is ignored

Tags: c, linux, static-variables

I have following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f1()
{
    static int s=10;
    printf("s=%d\n",s++);
}
int main()
{
    f1();
    f1();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
s=10
s=11
```

Why is the line `static int s=10` ignored at the second time, when `f1` is called?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program) and [this tutorial](http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.6.html) on static variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is no assignment, but an *initializer*. Local `static` variables are only initialized once at program startup like global variables. They keep their last *assigned* value even between invocations of the function. Thus after your first call, it retains the value `11`. In fact, they are like file-scope `static` variables, with their name only known in the scope of the block they are declared (but you can pass them by pointer).

Drawback is they only exist once. If you invoke the same function from multiple threads, they all share the **same** variable.

Try a third call: you will get `12`.

Note: the *initializer* must be a constant expression. Try `static int s = 10, t = s + 5;` and read the compiler error message.

Comment: sorry my mistake it is initialization.

Answer (score 7):

Initialization of a static variable is one-time (with the time of initialization guaranteed to occur before the first call, which could occur at compile time or at run time; compiler dependent). That's the main reason to use them.

Comment: I understand this.But my question is in the second call to `f1`, the statement  of initialization is ignored?only next statement gets executed.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's what "one-time" means; the initialization is only performed once (possibly before you even call the function for the first time), and never again; one subsequent calls of `f1`, it definitely __won't__ be performed.

Answer (score 4):

The `static` variables are initialized only once, conceptually even before application has started.

From C11 (N1570) §5.1.2/p1 *Execution environments*:

> All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to
>   their initial values) before program startup.

along with §6.2.4/p3 *Storage durations of objects*:

> Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored
>   value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

Comment: Do you mean before application has started means at compile time?

Comment: Not necessarily, that is up to the compiler.

Comment: @arya: The value must be known at compile time, so it is likely to happen in this way.

Comment: Typically there is a snippet of code linked to your program which executes the static initialization before main() is called, usually referred to as "copy-down" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, a `static` variable at function scope is initialized only once.  So the assignment doesn't happen on subsequent calls to the function.

Unlike other local variables, a `static` local is not defined on the stack but in the data segment, probably in the same location as global variables.  Globals are also initialized at application startup (they have to, since they don't live inside of a function and therefore can't be executable code), so conceptually you can think of a `static` variable as a global variable with limited visibility.

Comment: Or rather, all `static` variables have _static storage duration_, as do any file scope ("global") variables. All such variables follow the same rules of initialization and duration. Whether they end up in `.data` or `.bss` segment depends on if they are initialized to a value or zero. Don't think of static variables as global variables... think of static variables _and_ global variables as variables with static storage duration. Also, please don't use the term "function scope" as that refers to goto labels. The correct term is block scope or local scope.

Answer (score 1):

From the C89 Standard [HTML version](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html) at 3.1.2.4 *Storage durations of objects* it specifies:

> An object declared with external or internal linkage, **or with the storage-class specifier static has static storage duration. For such an object, storage is reserved and its stored value is initialized only once**, prior to program startup. The object exists and retains its last-stored value throughout the execution of the entire program

(The emphasis is mine)

So it says that everytime you use the static qualifier, that variable preserves its value across multiple function calls.
Local variables that are not static are initialized everytime you call the function that delcares them, so they do not preserve their value across function calls.

Hope this helped!

Comment: `static` is a specifier (as in the citation), not a qualifier. Note that C89 is not the valid standard; which is [C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html).

Comment: thank you! I used C89 for a bit, so I'm still using that :)

Comment: There have been quite some advances with C99. Some have different semantics and type-checking has been strengthened. You really should advance. (You would not drive a Ford Pinto (pick any other 70ies rotting model) anymore, wouldn't you?)